# Multiply two pandas dataframe with similar columns

Tags: python, pandas, matrix-multiplication

my `df1` with the shape `(5050, 63)` where every column holds `video_id` and row represent boolean value, wether user has watched it or not. 
My `df2` with the shape `(63,2)`, where the first row holds `video_id` and the second row `video_duration`

I want to multiply two dataframes, to calculate overall duration of videos, user has watched.

For this reason I transposed `df2` and converted to numeric values.

```
df_video_t = df_video_info.transpose()
new_header = df_video_t.iloc[0]
df_video_t = df_video_t[1:]
df_video_t.columns = new_header
df_video_t = df_video_t.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```

Then, I try to multiply `df1` to `df2`,

```
df_1.mul(df_2_t, axis=0)
```

but I instead of multiplication result, I recieve NaN in every cell.

My columns of the `df1` and row of `df2` are not sorted.
How should I do multiplication properly?

Comment: I'm assuming you're looking for a dot product? `r = df_1.values.dot(df_2_t.T.values)`

Comment: @COLDSPEED yes, you are definitely right! Thanks!

Comment: Sure, I've written an answer. Please vote on, and accept as you so wish. Thanks.

Comment: no problem, bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to perform a dot product on the values. This should be pretty fast -

```
r = df_1.values.dot(df_2_t.values.T)
```